# How to format a java.sql Timestamp for displaying?

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

How do I formate a java.sql Timestamp to my liking ? ( to a string, for display purposes)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`. You can do:

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(myTimestamp);
```

Or to also include time:

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(myTimestamp);
```

Comment: That'll work, but beware since SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe.

Comment: Just a small reminder that if SimpleDateFormat object is a local-scoped object (it is created and used only inside a method), then it is thread-safe, since stack on which it will reside is inherently "thread-safe" (as it belongs to a single thread).

Comment: To include time you will need to use SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") or something similar

Comment: to make it complete for those who needs it,
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(myTimestamp);

Comment: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` for those that have an IDE acting dumb on them.

Answer (score 32):

Use String.format (or [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)):

```
Timestamp timestamp = ...
String.format("%1$TD %1$TT", timestamp)
```

**EDIT:**
please see the documentation of Formatter to know what TD and TT means: click on [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

The first 'T' stands for:

```
't', 'T'    date/time   Prefix for date and time conversion characters.
```

and the character following that 'T':

```
'T'     Time formatted for the 24-hour clock as "%tH:%tM:%tS".
'D'     Date formatted as "%tm/%td/%ty".
```

Comment: This is the best answer, according to me. No superfluous object is created just for converting the timestamp to a string.

Comment: Now it should be clear where to find the documentation and what it means

Comment: Very elegant. Just to be clear, the formatting produced by the example here looks like `05/30/17 00:39:18`.

Comment: @Noumenon thanks, that was the format "to my liking" as the question demanded [:-)

Answer (score 10):

If you're using MySQL and want the database itself to perform the conversion, use this:

[DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

If you prefer to format using Java, use this:

[java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
dateFormat.format( new Date() );
```

Answer (score 10):

For this particular question, the standard suggestion of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` works, but has the unfortunate side effect that `SimpleDateFormat` **[is not thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#synchronization)** and can be the source of particularly nasty problems since it'll corrupt your output in multi-threaded scenarios, and you won't get any exceptions!

I would *strongly* recommend looking at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for anything like this. Why ? It's a much richer and more intuitive time/date library for Java than the current library (and the basis of the up-and-coming new standard Java date/time library, so you'll be learning a soon-to-be-standard API).

Comment: Good warning.  But very easy to address - don't share SimpleDateFormat instances by storing them in session scope / instance variables / static context and then accessing them from multiple threads.  Just create a new SimpleDateFormat() within your method and discard it after use.  That is threadsafe.

Comment: Of course if you really want to store/share SimpleDateFormat instance, then synchronise access:  synchronized(simpleDateFormatInstance) {s = simpleDateFormatInstance.format(myTimeStamp)}  OR create a custom extension of SDF class, and do this automatically within the format method.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`DateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). In an internationalized application, use the format provide by [`getInstance`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getInstance()). If you want to explicitly control the format, create a new [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I am providing the modern answer. The `Timestamp` class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class and is long outdated. I am assuming, though, that you are getting a `Timestamp` from a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now. When you do that, convert it to a modern `Instant` and do further processing from there.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    
    Timestamp oldfashionedTimestamp = new Timestamp(1_567_890_123_456L);
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = oldfashionedTimestamp.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String desiredFormat = dateTime.format(formatter);
    
    System.out.println(desiredFormat);
```

Output in my time zone:

> 07.09.2019 23:02:03

Pick how long or short of a format you want by specifying `FormatStyle.SHORT`, `.MEDIUM`, `.LONG` or `.FULL`. Pick your own locale where I put `Locale.GERMAN`. And pick your desired time zone, for example `ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo")`. A `Timestamp` is a point in time without time zone, so we need a time zone to be able to convert it into year, month, day, hour, minute, etc. If your `Timestamp` comes from a database value of type `timestamp` without time zone (generally not recommended, but unfortunately often seen), `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is likely to give you the correct result. Another and slightly simpler option in this case is instead to convert to a `LocalDateTime` using `oldfashionedTimestamp.toLocalDateTime()` and then format the `LocalDateTime` in the same way as I did with the `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score -15):

String timeFrSSHStr = timeFrSSH.toString();