# What about TimeFormat? Converting Timestamp

Tags: java, string, formatting, time-format

[How to format a java.sql Timestamp for displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156468/how-to-format-a-java-sql-timestamp-for-displaying)

What about TimeFormat, how can I convert a Timestamp as a String showing the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it...

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Date(timestamp.getTime()));
```

**EDIT**: Actually it turns out SimpleDateFormat can also format Timestamps so this is even easier:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    .format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: The java.sql.Timestamp extends java.util.Date class so you can format/parse anything that comes in the hierarchy. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html to format dates and timestamps.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
for (int i = 0; i < myDate.length; ++i) {
    output.println(df.format(myDate[i]) + "; ");
}
```