# TimeStamp patten

Tags: java, sql

```
Calendar firstTime =Calendar.getInstance();

java.sql.Timestamp t1=new Timestamp(firstTime.getTime().getTime());
```

It is giving current Time like this

```
`2015-01-06 17:19:20.763`
```

But i want timestamp pattern like below

```
'06-DEC-15 17:19:20.763000000 PM'
```

what do i do if i want to print timestamp  pattern like this

could someone help me please

Comment: Do you both want a 24h hour and the AM/PM marker?

Comment: yes, i want both 24 hour and AM/PM marker

Comment: Do you want to print it or store it in a database? If first look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156468/how-to-format-a-java-sql-timestamp-for-displaying)

Comment: What are you actually using the timestamp for? If it's going to a database then how it's formatted to a string doesn't matter, just map your object to a query parameter.

Comment: i had problem like i have taken a timestamps from java code and want to pass those to plsql procedure where in parameters are timestamp types, but plsql procedure is not taking those timestamps i feel that java timestamp and sql timestamp are not compatable to each other. that's why i have posted question like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat:

```
        Calendar firstTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
        df.applyPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSS000000 aa");

        System.out.println(df.format(firstTime.getTimeInMillis()).toUpperCase());
```

I have put "0"s after SSS because the time you get is in miliseconds and it doesn't make any sense to have more than three "S"s but that's the requirement.

The toUpperCase is another requirement("Jan" was not enough).

Comment: @mqsuresh "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa "is exactly the pattern you want.

Comment: thank you, it is very fine it is giving like          06-Jan-15 05:34:28.000000846 PM ,,,but i need like  06-Jan-15  05:34:28.846000000PM

Comment: @demostene Not exactly — `MMM` will not give uppercase output (as in example) and is locale dependent (eg. this pattern gives 'sty' for my locale and January). Also the original output contains 24H format, not 12H (hence you need `HH` instead of `hh`).

Answer (score 1):

If you strongly insist on the particular output format (1:1), you should use `DateFormatSymbols` additionally.

```
    final DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setShortMonths(new String[]{
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"});
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSS000000 a", dfs);
    System.out.println(df.format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

And please remember, that `DateFormat` is **not** thread-safe.

Comment: @mqsuresh Still this one prints 06-JAN-15 12:47:52.000000637 PM and not 06-JAN-15 12:47:52.637000000 PM. Have a look at my solution.

Comment: @demostene You're right — you need those zeros, thou they are actually pointless, as there is no more precision in **MILI**seconds (1/1000 of second) that 3 digits. And unless you make use of `System.nanoTime` you can't get more precision from `Timestamp`. And as for your solution: `toUpperCase` is not sufficient, as it will break on many different locales.

Comment: I haven't seen any Locale requirements.

Comment: Pattern of `MMM` will display so called "short month", but this short month string depends on current locale. In other words, without setting explicitly `Locale` to English (or better using `DateFormatSymbols` to avoid unnecessary `toUpperCase`, which BTW may be inappropriate when pattern changes), you can't guarantee to output `"JAN"` for January on every JVM instance. But with setting `shortMonths` on `DateFormatSymbols` instance passed to `DateFormat` constructor — you can.