# insert timestamp by hibernate anh html

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I use spring mvc and hibernate with h2 database ,the following code store date value in this format 2015-01-14 but I want to store timestamp value in this format
2015-01-14 21:32:29 ,How can I do that?

attribute decleration in Entity

```
@Column(name = "updatetimestamp", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date  updatetimestamp;
```

html code for timestamp column

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Update Timestamp</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                  ng-model="contact.updatetimestamp">
   </div>
```

H2 Database table

```
     <createTable tableName="T_CONTACT">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="email" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <!--<column name="description" type="varchar(5000)"/>-->
        <column name="UpdateTimestamp" type="timestamp"/>
    </createTable>
```

Comment: Make sure the field `updatetimestamp`  is not `java.sql.Date` . Usually `java.util.Date` works fine, but you might want to use joda library for date/time

Answer (score 0):

The usual java.sql.Timestamp is formatted like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms
```

Try this code to see how it works:

```
Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date);
        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(stamp);
```

This topic seems to be helpful for your intentions:
[How to format a java.sql Timestamp for displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156468/how-to-format-a-java-sql-timestamp-for-displaying)